# Loading Drools 6 KIE JAR into code fail with runtime exception Cannot find KieModule

Tags: drools, kie

I am using drools 6.0.1.Final and eclipse Luna

I am trying to load the jar from my maven repo

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(
ks.newReleaseId("com.drools.demo",   "myProject", "LATEST"));
KieScanner kScanner = ks.newKieScanner( kContainer );
kScanner.start( 10000L );

KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("defaultKieSession");
```

Kie workbench points to my maven repo which deployed the jar directly to my repo. I have also tried installing jar through maven install, but nothing works

I found some similar posts on stackoverflow and none of them are answered, is it a bug in drools 6?

Comment: Some of them may not be answered due to imprecise formulations in the question. Here, for instance: Which jar? Where is the exception thrown? Stack trace? What is the code where it is thrown?

Comment: If its not coming even by using mvn install then It seems to be an issue with maven settings or your deployment to repo.

Answer (score 0):

Do You have a `kmodule.xml` file in the `META-INF` folder of Your Maven project?

This is what You need to add to the Maven project with rules (**note:** the part in red should be added in "special" cases, so **try without the red part first**):

[image: kmodule.xml configuration]

Notice how the `packages` field contains the name of the folder where rules (`.drl` files) are located.